# What is an overview of Judaism's arguments against the "unconscious violinist" analogy used to support abortion in the case of rape?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, sexuality, mussar-ethics, murder

I am looking for the response of **any denomination** that is against abortion in the case of rape that has also responded to the scenario below or something similar to it.

"[A Defense of Abortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Defense_of_Abortion#The_Violinist)" (Thomson):

> You wake up in the morning and find yourself back to back in bed with
>   an unconscious violinist. A famous unconscious violinist. He has been
>   found to have a fatal kidney ailment, and the Society of Music Lovers
>   has canvassed all the available medical records and found that you
>   alone have the right blood type to help. They have therefore kidnapped
>   you, and last night the violinist's circulatory system was plugged
>   into yours, so that your kidneys can be used to extract poisons from
>   his blood as well as your own. [If he is unplugged from you now, he
>   will die; but] in nine months he will have recovered from his ailment,
>   and can safely be unplugged from you.

It is said later that:

> Critics of Thomson's argument generally grant the permissibility of
>   unplugging the violinist, but seek to block the inference that
>   abortion is permissible by arguing that there are morally relevant
>   differences between the violinist scenario and typical cases of
>   abortion.

But it is **unsourced**. :(

To make my intentions clear, the above is an analogy for a female being raped and impregnated by a male. **Some denominations claim that the female is obliged to carry the child to birth if medically practical** because the child is innocent of his/her father's sins, has a right to life, etc etc etc.

(Assume ideal conditions such as medical complications not being present so the mother and child are healthy, the mother can give birth, the mother and the father are not close relatives, a proper hospital is available and can be afforded, an adoption agency is available etc etc etc)

**So do those arguments apply to the violinist too?** What are the "morally relevant differences" ? I understand that Thomson was defending abortion in non-rape cases, but let us consider only rape cases.

What's the difference? Why are women responsible for carrying a child, who she did not consent to carrying, to birth but people are not responsible for caring for a violinist who they were attached to without consent?

I am not saying women are not responsible, but **if they are, it looks like everyone is responsible for the violinist.**

Comment: Are you assuming that she could unplug from the violinist but would not be allowed to from the child? Maybe she also wouldn't be allowed to from the violinist.

Comment: This sounds like the Siamese twin problem in which one would survive if they are separated http://www.jlaw.com/Commentary/cojoinedtwins.html

Comment: Why in the world is it so obvious that the "you" in the thought experiment can unplug himself? My immediate reaction was to assume that "you" would be morally prohibited from doing anything that kills anyone else (at least directly, but we'd have to quibble over what "directly" means)

Comment: @sabbahillel Isn't the issue there that they can't survive this way and that they are, or one is, a Rodef?

Comment: Echoing @Matt, my immediate (informed) instinct is that it would in fact be *halachically* prohibited to disconnect from the violinist if there is no threat to the healthy person in remaining connected. Incidentally, it would make no moral or *halachic* difference whether the ill person was a violinist, a janitor, or an unemployed person who provides no known utility to society.

Comment: @Fred How is the idea of laying in a hospital bed for nine months not a threat? Think about the opportunities wasted. The person connected to the violinist could do a lot of good in the world. An answer I got on philosophy and another in christianity stackexchange says pregnant women can still go about doing good in the world. also, abortion is intended while the violinist dying is an unintended side effect of unplugging. does judaism or your denomination disagree with the doctrine of double effect?

Comment: @RedRackham The doctrine of double effect is not especially well-defined, and Jewish law cannot readily be framed in those terms. But in the trolley problem, for example, Judaism prohibits saving five people by killing one person. In the violinist case, once the status quo would allow him to live, disconnecting him would be an affirmative act of murder, and you may not disconnect him absent him posing a threat to your life. Judaism does not use utilitarian considerations to decide whose life is worth more.

Comment: @Fred Catholicism is DEFINITELY not utilitarian. Most mainstream religions are not.  Why is doctrine of double effect not well-defined? Are you sure you have the authority to speak on behalf of an entire religion and not simply for your particular denomination?

Comment: @RedRackham 1. Re. utilitarian considerations, I wasn't referring to Catholicism specifically. I was responding to your remark about "opportunities wasted." 2. People seem to have somewhat different ideas about the implications of that doctrine. I'm certainly no expert on double effect as such, and I don't think there's much value in me voting "yea" or "nay" on it on behalf of Judaism. 3. I'm sure I don't have any vested authority to speak on behalf of any denomination. I'm just informing you of what seems to be the standard legal view that has traditionally marked Judaism over the centuries.

Comment: @Fred traditionally and thus not completely?

Answer (score 8):

Rabbi Yosef Karo (1488 - 1575)states in Shulchan Aruch, (The Code of Jewish Law) that if a physician is able to heal a patient and refrains from doing so, **this is considered murder**. Yoreh Deah, 336:1

Rabbi Moshe Isserles (The Rema 1520 - 1572), writes on the Shulchan Aruch (Code of Jewish Law), that any act involving touching or moving a "gossess" (a term referring to a patient close to death) is prohibited because such an act may hasten his death. He continues by stating that if the act does hasten death **it is considered murder**. (Yoreh Deah, 339:1)

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (1895 - 1986), one of the greatest and mainstream authorities on Orthodox Jewish Law in recent times, based on the above Rema, comments: "...even if the patient is suffering, [if an action is done to hasten his death] **it is the crime of murder**, and it is **absolutely forbidden** and he is liable to the punishment for murder… [This is true] even if (the sick person)is one who is suffering greatly and [the physician] murders with merciful intent and even if it is requested [by the patient].” Igros Moshe, Choshen Mishpat II, 83:1

Orthodox Judaism certainly does not allow removal of life support in a person that will survive and be cured. (example, the violinist)

Judaism teaches that we must obey morality as a responsibility. Protecting the violinist's life, outweighs personal inconvenience. Even though the violinist or kidnappers, may have done the wrong thing, the fact remains that human life must be preserved. (However, the violinist may be liable to pay his benefactor a hefty sum for damages.)

In order to disconnect from the violinist, one would need to prove, from Torah sources, that their 9 months of inconvenience and loss, outweighs one human life. That's going to be pretty hard to do.

Even secular courts understand this. If I am driving a car, and someone jumps in front of my path in the road and makes silly gestures at me etc. Do I run him over because he has no right to be in my way? What if my defense was that I needed to hit him with my car, because if I swerved, I would damage my car and need a few thousand dollars of repairs?

BTW, Orthodox Judaism, does not forbid abortion in all cases. We do forbid abortion on demand, but may permit abortion for great need (like cases of saving the mother etc. This includes certain cases of rape according to some Orthodox Jewish opinions.) But that is not the focus of the OP. I am just pointing out that Thompson seems to assume as a given for the sake of her example, that a fetus does have the same right to life as a viable human after birth. Judaism does not agree with that across the board.

Maimonides (Rambam, 1135 - 1204) in his Code of Jewish Law, says that (based on the Talmud) if a baby is causing danger to the mother's life it should be aborted; however if its head has emerged, then the two lives are equal. Hilchos Rotzeach 1:9

The Torah supports the idea that killing a fetus is wrong (but it is not a murder punishable by death). See Exodus 21:22, where the Torah forces someone who caused a miscarriage, to pay for monetary damages.

However, Judaism does accept the sanctity of the life of a fetus. (and obviously a person) Therefore, we are responsible for the unborn life, and the violinist as well. The reason is that our focus on our responsibility to preserve life usually trumps the assumed fault of the living party. It is not about what is fair, rather, what is right.

Comment: +1 but a small quibble. If the violinist was complicit in the conspiracy, that may change things. You wrote that it doesn't matter what brought about the circumstance, but some situations may classify the violinist as a Rodef.

Comment: @Yishai, I don't see anything in the scenario, as stated, indicating that the subject's health  is endangered. That's required to get a *rodef* status, isn't it?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, consider הבא במחתרת - the ultimate determination of the person to endanger the subject *may* get them that status. After all, the conspirators would rather risk the victim's life (even though killing him outright would defeat the purpose) than let him go and have the violinist die.

Comment: @Yishai, I still don't see any indication that any such danger is postulated in the scenario. "הבא במחתרת," in particular, adds a special assumption that anyone invading your house is presumably willing to endanger your life if confronted.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, seems pretty obvious to me that anyone willing to go to the lengths of this scenario might be subject to the same type of assumption.

Comment: @Yishai, I don't know; you're dealing with a special decree of Scripture, and while I'd agree with you that during the kidnapping in progress, the kidnappers could be assumed, based on this decree, to be dangerous, I don't see how it applies after the fact, when the subject is peacefully hooked up. I guess you're afraid that if the subject tries to unhook, the conspirators might now pull a gun to compel her to stop?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, yes, that would be an example. They may say better that you die, or they may say, well we will sedate you with dangerous drugs, or restrain you in dangerous ways, rather than let you go, that kind of thing. But I also think there may be wider applications to this principle, although I don't have time to look it up now.

Comment: `We do forbid abortion on demand` whose "we"? The Tzitz Eliezer? Rav Moshe? Rav Shelomo Zalman?

Comment: `This includes certain cases of rape according to some Orthodox Jewish opinions` Which opinions? It seems that the most crucial parts of this answer are left to vague unsourced assertions.

Comment: @ Mevaqesh, The OP was not directed at those issues. These are not crucial parts of the answer at all. It was written after "BTW", to help the author of the OP recognize why the violinist analogy may not apply in every case of abortion. Check Shalom's response below which did a nice job.

Answer (score 3):

To consolidate the comments above: at first glance, Jewish law would prohibit unplugging the violinist too -- assuming being plugged in is no threat to your life. So it's kind of a moot point.

We care about the situation at hand, not passing judgment on how it came about.

(There is certainly discussion about pregnancies that threaten the mother's mental health, and a product of rape could certainly be in that category. But that still depends entirely on the mother's situation.)

Jewish law may in fact be more lenient about an abortion than a plugged-in violinist as the latter was already "fully living", but that's a different discussion.

Comment: There is also the forty day period in which there is seemingly no issue in the first place.

Comment: @HaLeiVi beyond the scope of this question.